# Why @media is not overriding the default value?

Tags: css

I have a `@media` that is not working for some reason.

When I resize my browser under 768px, I  can see the CSS rules popup in the browser but they have no effect. The Buttons still have 245px width.

[image: Image of my browser]

CSS:

```
#product-tabs button{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 245px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    background: #fff;
    color: #444444;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

#product-tabs button.active {
    background: #288d95;
    border: 1px solid #288d95;
    color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
    #product-tabs button{
        max-width: 180px;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
i found the problem, min-width CANT be higher than max-width

i change the css to this

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
  #product-tabs button{
     max-width: 180px;
     min-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because CSS rules inside `@media` are not treated with more specificity than CSS outside a `@media` block.

Therefore, the correct solution is to move the @media query at the end of the CSS:

```
#product-tabs button {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 245px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    background: #fff;
    color: #444444;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

#product-tabs button.active {
    background: #288d95;
    border: 1px solid #288d95;
    color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #product-tabs button{
        max-width: 180px;
    }
}
```

Comment: still same issue this do not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

`max-width` and `min-width` are 2 different CSS properties and one can not override other. In this case, I think you need to `unset` the `min-width` first using the media query and then use the `max-width` rule so that it can take effect.

```css
#product-tabs button{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 245px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    background: #fff;
    color: #444444;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

#product-tabs button.active {
    background: #288d95;
    border: 1px solid #288d95;
    color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
    #product-tabs button{
        min-width: unset;
        max-width: 180px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="product-tabs">
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
```